# How to get 1, 3 and 5 year KM survival for large database using SPSS?

Tags: spss, survival, kaplan-meier

I have large database of hundreds of thousands observations. When I used spss to analyze KM survival, it gave me mean and median survivals with 95 % confidence interval. However, I need 1-, 3- and 5- year survival too. It's difficult to figure out using the curves. I am missing something? I also tried life tables, but I am not sure about it's accuracy? Can anyone please throw light here?

Answer (score 2):

SPSS's Kaplan-Meier procedure should give a "survival table" that provides estimates of survival probability and its SE at each time.

See example [Table 2.3 this posted example](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/examples/asa2/chap2.htm).

Comment: OMG!this is so helpful! Thanks Rioraider. I cant believe that I could not this figure out because I have been working on it for almost a year and didn't realize this. Thanks again for answering.